# Get all twitter feed in my blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, twitter

I playing around with the Twitter API for my BlackBerry application. Is there any library through which I can access Twitter information? I want to pull feeds in my Twitter account.

Comment: Why don't you just request xml from your twitter xml feed and then parse it? Or have I understand you wrong?

Comment: You are right. Yes that's only way right now i can see. We just need to get xml file and parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Max said, We can request the JSON response for twitter feeds.

Parse the JSON response as per your requirement.

In my case it is working through the JSON response.